# Margin affecting box shadow when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the box shadow to emulate a border. I can't use the border on all sides but I'm running into problems.

```
input[type=text]{
    float:left;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    height:40px;
    padding:0 80px 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: -79px 0 0 #ffffff inset, -80px 0 0 0 #c5cbcf inset, 0 1px 0 0 #c5cbcf inset, 0 -1px 0 0 #c5cbcf inset;
}
```

I need to do it this way since there is something sitting to the right of the box. This shows fine but when I resize the browser’s window the shadows come and go. If it set the width to 2px they stay all the time but get wider and thinner. If I adjust the margins it solves it at one point but then affects it at the different point.

Is they any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you maybe link us to a js fiddle or your website showing the problem

Comment: Why are you using a negative value on the box shadow? (-79px)

Comment: To get the border to the right. With the element that goes on the right, I need to use the -79 to get the border before that elements starts, hence the reason for using a border box, having a large right padding and not being able to use a normal border.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
transform: none !important;
will-change: unset !important;
```